# Android Device (QMobileA60)not connecting to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I am currently working on eclipse, but I am unable to connect my device to Eclipse. It's visible in the system and i have enabled debugging option as well. I have searched a lot on internet but now I'm hell fedup. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device cannot connected has many reason.
I think the first you should check the device work mode,some device has PTP or MTP mode,you should try change the mode.http://lh3.ggpht.com/-8UMNs7Vg_dY/UVC6_6PnbDI/AAAAAAAAAIg/NjKOvAp9cDs/02-select-camera-ptp-mode_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png%3Fimgmax%3D800
Next you can check the adb port is other program is using.You can open DDMS,try this `reset adb` option(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev8Z3.jpg ). Or  open terminal and execute command `lsof -i:5037`.This is adb work port. If some program use it. Use command `kill -9 {pid}` kill the program.
Finally you can try using another cable.

Comment: Are you try reset adb?

Comment: Device cannot connected has many reason. I think the first you should check the device work mode,some device has PTP or MTP mode,you should try change the mode. Next you can check the adb port is other program is using. Finally you can try using another cable.

Comment: @Naila You can click the Reset adb option

Comment: can you please guide, how to check the device work mode? The cable works fine, as i had used it on android studio on my mac

Comment: Some device at drop-down notification bar. http://lh3.ggpht.com/-8UMNs7Vg_dY/UVC6_6PnbDI/AAAAAAAAAIg/NjKOvAp9cDs/02-select-camera-ptp-mode_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png%3Fimgmax%3D800 .  If the mode is right, You can open terminal and execute command `lsof -i:5037`.This is adb work port.  If some program use it. Use command `kill -9 {pid}`  kill the program.

Comment: @Rico, i think you should update your answer and mention the comment part over there as well.. so that it might help others

Comment: @FayzaNawaz thanks your recommend,I have updated the answer.